# Unable to call pickle load function on Ubuntu 22.04 EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, scikit-learn, pickle

I am using the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) operation to serialize my machine learning algorithms and save the serialized format to a file. And then using the load function to unpack them.

I have a 3GB model (model.sav) that I created via scikit. When loading the model on a server I deployed (Ubuntu 22.04 t2.medium EC2 Instance) via a Python 3.8.5 script:

```
fn = os.path.join('/mnt/temp/model.sav')

try:
    model = pickle.load(open(fn, 'rb'))
except:
    print("unable to open model")
    exit()
```

I get:

> killed

In the console with no information. Not even the except handler is called.

I tried upgrading the instance to t2.2xlarge to see if anything changes as I thought it was a memory issue. And it still showed killed. I don't know if upgrading again to a larger instance is the solution

What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: What version of Python are you using (`python3 --version` should work on Ubuntu)?

Comment: @stdunbar Python 3.8.5

Comment: Never use a bare `try: except:` - you'll never know what the real error is. Unwrap that block to begin with (but really, `"Killed"` does sound like a memory issue).

Comment: "Killed" is most often caused by the kernel's out of memory handler.

Comment: as I remember different Python's versions could used different method to pickle data and file `pickle` created by i.e `3.7` couldn't be used by ie.`3.8`. Better use other method to work with data on different computers.

Comment: sklearn doc [9. Model persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) suggests to use `joblib.dump`, `joblib.load` instead of `pickle`

Comment: @furas I tried joblib instead and the issue still persists. I will use it though in the future so thanks for the recommendation

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you use `joblib` to create this file? And first you should run code without `try/except` to see full error message - it may gives you more useful information.